# Using C# DLL linked with IKVM DLLs in Borland Delphi 7

Tags: java, c#, delphi, com, ikvm

I have a C# DLL that serves as a wrapper for my Java code (I generated a DLL from Java code using **IKVM**). Now I want to call C# DLL methods that use Java code methods from Delphi 7.

Here is a code for of the C# function:

```
   [DllExport]
    public static void GetAnswer()
    {
        //this is IKVM's ArrayList. Without this line the function call works fine
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
    }
```

I register my function in Delphi as:

```
 function GetAnswer() : Pointer; stdcall; external 'MyDllName.dll'
```

When calling GetAnswer() I get a Delphi exception: *External Exception E0434352*
Without ArrayList creation in the DLL function GetAnswer() finishes successfully.
I have my ikvm DLLs in PATH env variable located in the same folder where MyDllName.dll resides.

I suppose it has something to do with the fact that IKVM DLLs are possibly not COM compatible, but I'm not an expert here. So the question is: is it at all possible to do the stuff I'm trying to do, and if yes, what steps should I take?

Any pointers are highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
As suggested by David, the COM mentioning might be irrelevant here.

Comment: Hard to see why COM is relevant. I cannot see any COM. Do you have any reason to bring COM into this, or are you just guessing? If the latter then it may be better not to mention it. Also, the Delphi function should be `procedure GetAnswer; stdcall; external ...` details are crucial in interop. The detail errors that can be seen make me wonder whether there are other errors that we cannot see. I also wonder if there is more code. Surely you could have presented and entire C# DLL? It would only have taken a handful more lines of code.

Comment: I'm coming from a Java world, so I might be not completely competent here. I mentioning COM because when searching internet I saw many mentionings of registering a DLL for COM compatibility in Visual Studio. However, I still didn't learn enough to make a definitive conlustion

Comment: I don't think COM is at all relevant here. The reason I ask for a complete program is that I worry that there is actually something else causing the problem that we cannot see. Cutting a problem down to a bare minimum is a good way to shine a light on what the root cause is. Do you see the problem with a C# managed DLL that contains just that one method? It would also be interesting to see if you can consume the C# managed DLL from a C# host. And It would also be useful to see your Delphi host. Ideally that should be a very simple console application. Then your entire program can be posted.

Comment: I would need some time to come up with a minimum program, but I already have a test C# program that links against my DLL and all IKVM classes and methods  work fine, in particular, I'm able to execute my DLL function GetAnswer() without any problems. Also if I instantiate .NET ArrayList in my function, it also runs successfully from Delphi. All of these make me think that the problem is related to IKVM DLLs. Maybe I should load the IKVM DLLs explicitly in Delphi code?

Comment: A minimum program should not take long. It's just 10 lines of boiler plate around what you already have. That's what you should be working with anyway to be sure that you are isolating the right thing. If you presented that then I could attempt to debug. Without that I can't be sure that I wouldn't be wasting my time debugging something different from you.

Comment: I just won't have access to Windows machine until later today. Totally understand that it's not worth debugging before I provide a program. However, still interesting whether I should explicitly load dependent DLLs (in my case IKVM DLLs) from Delphi

Comment: I don't think you should have to load DLLs explicitly. I see no reason for that.